# SQLITE CREATE VIEW Syntax issues with JOIN

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, syntax

Having a bit of trouble in CREATE VIEW with JOIN when I try to join 3 tables together, I can do 2 but 3 seems to be a no go for me. I'm new to this so I'm just going by trial and error since most of the documentations I've gone through didn't really cover ( to my understanding ) joining 3 tables and it's not really going well so here I am for some advice and hopefully a solution. Thanks in advance.

Here are the tables:

Terms

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + termsTable + " (" + colTermsID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " + colTermsClass + " TEXT)");
```

Status

```
  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + statTable + " (" + colStatusID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " + colStatClass + " TEXT)");
```

Accounts

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + accountsTable + " (" + colID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            colName + " TEXT, " +
            colAmount + " Integer, " +
            colPurpose + " TEXT, " +
            colTerms +" INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            colStatus +" INTEGER DEFAULT '1'," +
            colDate + " TEXT, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY (" + colTerms + ") REFERENCES " + termsTable + " (" + colTermsID + ") " + "," +
            "FOREIGN KEY (" + colStatus + ") REFERENCES " + statTable + " (" + colStatusID + "));");
```

This is the CREATE VIEW I'm using which works fine with just one of either Terms or Status but not when I try to use both so I assume I'm doing something wrong in that area.

```
    db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW " + viewAccs +
                    " AS SELECT " + accountsTable + "." + colID + " AS _id," +
                    " " + accountsTable + "." + colName + "," +
                    " " + accountsTable + "." + colAmount + "," +
                    " " + accountsTable + "." + colPurpose + "," +
                    " " + termsTable + "." + colTermsClass + "" +
                    " FROM " + accountsTable + " JOIN " + termsTable + " ON " + accountsTable + "." + colTerms + " = " + termsTable + "." + colTermsID +
                    " " + statTable + "." + colStatClass + "" +
                    " FROM " + accountsTable+ " JOIN " + statTable + " ON " + accountsTable + "." + colStatus + " = " + statTable + "." + colStatusID +
                    " " + accountsTable + "." + colDate
    );
```

EDIT ( ANSWER HERE ):

This is the actual code for future reference I ended up with after fixing the Syntax and following what X.L Ant mentioned.

```
            db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW " + viewAccs +
                    " AS SELECT " + accountsTable + "." + colID + " AS _id," +
                    " " + accountsTable + "." + colName + "," +
                    " " + accountsTable + "." + colAmount + "," +
                    " " + accountsTable + "." + colPurpose + "," +
                    " " + termsTable + "." + colTermsClass + "," +
                    " " + statTable + "." + colStatClass + "," +
                    " " + accountsTable + "." + colDate + "" +
                    " FROM " + accountsTable +
                    " JOIN " + termsTable + " ON " + accountsTable + "." + colTerms + " = " + termsTable + "." + colTermsID +
                    " JOIN " + statTable + " ON " + accountsTable + "." + colStatus + " = " + statTable + "." + colStatusID
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have two `FROM` in one query.

Try this:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW " + viewAccs +
                " AS SELECT " + accountsTable + "." + colID + " AS _id," +
                " " + accountsTable + "." + colName + "," +
                " " + accountsTable + "." + colAmount + "," +
                " " + accountsTable + "." + colPurpose + "," +
                " " + termsTable + "." + colTermsClass + "" +
                " FROM " + accountsTable + 
                " JOIN " + termsTable + " ON " + accountsTable + "." + colTerms + " = " + termsTable + "." + colTermsID +
                " " + statTable + "." + colStatClass + "" +
                " JOIN " + statTable + " ON " + accountsTable + "." + colStatus + " = " + statTable + "." + colStatusID +
                " " + accountsTable + "." + colDate
```

Make sure the variables you're injecting in your SQL are safe to avoid injection.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on that. This did work but with a few tweaks to it as well, mostly just the order of it all. Specifically I had to put the FROM and JOIN clauses at the end AFTER all of the columns not after the column that was going to use it. 

In regard to the actual code I ended up with for future reference I'll leave it in an EDIT in my main question. Thanks again for the help